# ClimaTempo API - Cidades com acento dão erro

Tags: java, ajax, json, api

Tenho o seguinte Endpoint na qual recebe na URI o nome da cidade e do estado:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/clima/{nomeCidade}/{ufCidade}/agora",  method = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.OPTIONS} , produces="application/json" )
public ResponseEntity<Clima> getClimaAgoraByNomeCidade(@PathVariable(value = "nomeCidade") String nomeCidade,  @PathVariable(value = "ufCidade") Estado ufCidade) throws JSONException, ParseException, java.text.ParseException {

    JSONObject detCidade = new JSONObject();
    ClimaTempoAPI ct = new ClimaTempoAPI();     

    String newNomeCidade = nomeCidade.toLowerCase().replace(" ", "%20");
    String weatherEndpoint = "/api/v1/locale/city?name=" + newNomeCidade + "&state=" + ufCidade.toString();
    Long idCidade;

    Integer findRegCidade = climaRepository.findCountCidade(ufCidade, nomeCidade);

    // Se a cidade existir no banco
    if(findRegCidade != 0) {

        // Atribuir o idCidade da cidade e fazer requisi�ao no banco
        idCidade = climaRepository.findTop1IdCidade(ufCidade, nomeCidade);

    // Se nao existir a cidade no banco, gravar a cidade e fazer a requisicao   
    } else {

        try {
            detCidade = ct.RequestWeather(weatherEndpoint);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        CidadeCT cidadeCT = new CidadeCT();
        cidadeCT.setId((long) System.currentTimeMillis());
        cidadeCT.setCodPais(detCidade.get("country").toString().trim());
        cidadeCT.setNomeCidade((String) detCidade.get("name"));
        idCidade = (Long) detCidade.get("id");
        cidadeCT.setIdCidade(idCidade);
        cidadeCT.setEstado(Enum.valueOf(Estado.class, detCidade.get("state").toString()));  
        cidadeCTRepository.save(cidadeCT);  

    }       

    return getClimaAgora(idCidade);


}
```

O método ct.RequestWeather() está da seguinte maneira:

```
public JSONObject RequestWeather(String weatherEndpoint) throws IOException, JSONException, ParseException {

    String appToken = "&token=xxx";     

    URL weatherDomain = new URL("http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br" + weatherEndpoint + appToken);

    return ConnectionJson.returnJson(weatherDomain, true);

}
```

E minha chamada AJAX no .js do Front-End está da seguinte maneira:

```
var uf = $("#colWeather #selectState").val();
var city = $("#colWeather #selectCity").val();    

//Send a request to the ClimaTempo Endpoint
$.ajax({
    url: host + '/clima/' + city + '/' + uf + '/agora',
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json",
    async: true
}).done(function (JSONReturn) {

      //Algumas ações aqui

});
```

Quando o nome da cidade NÃO TEM acento ele consegue pegar normalmente os dados de clima atuais. Mas cidade com acento (por exemplo: Avaí-SP, Arujá-SP) estou recebendo um erro 500:

```
   {
"timestamp":1530038926783,
"status":500,
"error":"Internal Server Error",
"exception":"org.json.simple.parser.ParseException",
"message":"No message available",
"path":"/clima/Altin%C3%B3polis/SP/agora"
}
```

O que estou fazendo de errado que cidade com acento ele sempre está dando problema?

**DETALHE: no LOCALHOST está funcionando perfeitamente! Mas quando subo para o servidor essas cidades com acento não funcionam.**

Comment: Veja se a URL gerada é exatamente a mesma no servidor e no seu local, para começar. Quando a cidade não é encontrada, vem um json com um array vazio ao invés de um objeto, acredito que pode ser isso. Abrindo direto o link em http://apiadvisor.climatempo.com.br/api/v1/locale/city?name=Altin%C3%B3polis&state=sp&token=xxx, retornou um objeto corretamente aqui pra mim.

Comment: No servidor a URL está chegando (pelo menos no log também) com esses símbolos ( %C3%B3 como no exemplo ).

Comment: Sim, esse é o `ó` do Antinópolis. Mas colando a URL tanto com ó quanto com esse código no lugar, o Json retorna no browser. Se você notar bem na mensagem, o erro ocorre no seu servidor, na hora de ler o Json de retorno. Se funciona em um servidor e no outro não, penso que pode ser URLs diferentes, ou que o outro servidor não consegue enxergar o site do climatempo... nesse servidor, tente acessar o link gerado manualmente pra testar por exemplo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Eu resolvi CODIFICANDO o nomeCidade que eu recebo via get ANTES de enviar para o Endpoint do ClimaTempo. Ficando da seguinte maneira:

```
//Encode the nomeCidade to send to the ClimaTempo Endpoint
//(This must be done because of the accents)

String newNomeCidade = nomeCidade.toLowerCase();
try {
    newNomeCidade = URLEncoder.encode(newNomeCidade, "UTF-8");
} catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e1.printStackTrace();
}       
JSONObject climaCidade = new JSONObject();
ClimaTempoAPI ct = new ClimaTempoAPI();

String weatherEndpoint = "/api/v1/locale/city?name=" + newNomeCidade + "&state=" + ufCidade.toString();
climaCidade = ct.RequestWeather(weatherEndpoint, appToken.getKey());
```

Usei o "nomeCidade.toLowerCase()" pois, por algum motivo, se a primeira letra do nome da cidade tivesse acento e fosse maiúscula, o endpoint da API do ClimaTempo retornava uma exceção, que só era resolvido se fosse tudo minusculo.